# How to get command's standard output with subprocess?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

For some reason, I want to gather the help message of some commands. In order to do it, I use the *subprocess* module in **Python3**. My code works fine for linux commands but not when I use it on BASH commands. Typically I want it to work on the *cd* BASH command.

Here is the snippet of code I use for now:

```
import subprocess

instruction = ["cat", "--help"]
proc = subprocess.run(instruction, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
return proc.stdout
```

As said before, it works fine and it returns the help message of the command *cat*.

Here is what it returns when I try to adapt my code in order to handle BASH commands:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.run("cd --help", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout
b''
```

My question is simple, is it possible to get BASH commands' help message using **Python3**. If so, how to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at what `subprocess.run` returns:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> result = subprocess.run("cd --help", shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> result
CompletedProcess(args='cd --help', returncode=1, stdout=b'', stderr=b'/bin/sh: line 0: cd: --: invalid option\ncd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir]\n')
```

Turns out, `cd --help` is an error:

```
$ cd --help
-bash: cd: --: invalid option
cd: usage: cd [-L|-P] [dir]
```

So you should look for it in `result.stderr`.